# simple paypal ipn always response invalid

Tags: php, paypal

This is my ipn listner code but when I open test file it says INVALID. 
 I'm just starting to learn this and it is the same code as the tutorial. 
 In the video it response VERIFIED. but in mine INVALID.

Can you please help me?

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
    header('index.php');
    exit() ;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"cmd=_notify-validate&".http_build_query($_POST) );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents("test.txt", $response);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's so for every case but the sample code I'm using sets
VERIFYHOST, 1
AND
VERIFYPEER, 2

You could try that to see what happens.